# kdb: parse QSQL statement gives extra enlist in conditional clause

Tags: kdb

Running `parse` on a QSQL query string seems to give one extra `enlist` for the where phrase. Why is that?

```
q)show x: parse "select from t where a=1"
?
`t
,,(=;`a;1)                     / <----
0b
()

q)x[2]~enlist (=;`a;1)         / WAS EXPECTING THIS TO BE 1b
0b

q)x[2]~enlist enlist (=;`a;1)  / INSTEAD GIVES THIS
1b
```

Asking because if we enlist it twice, it doesn't work:

```
q)t:([]a:1 2);

q)?[`t;enlist(=;`a;1);0b;()]
a
-
1

q)?[`t;enlist enlist(=;`a;1);0b;()]
'type
  [0]  ?[`t;enlist enlist(=;`a;1);0b;()]
       ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This topic is covered in detail in a whitepaper:

https://code.kx.com/q/wp/parse-trees/#issues-converting-to-functional-form

The key section:

> passing a select query to parse ...... each returned item is in
> unevaluated form. As discussed above, simply applying value to a parse
> tree does not work. However, if we evaluate each one of the arguments
> fully, then there would be no nested parse trees. We could then apply
> value to the result

Parse trees are evaluated by `eval` but `q)` prompt uses `value`

The nested parse trees as returned can be evaluated by `eval`:

```
q)-1 .Q.s1 parse "select from t where a=1"
(?;`t;,,(=;`a;1);0b;())

q)eval (?;`t;enlist enlist(=;`a;1);0b;())
a
-
1
```